# Tensorflow and Python Terminology and Language

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am a statistician, so my relationship with Python and Tensorflow is relatively limited and English is not my native language, so I want to make sure I got the terminology right for this meme I'm making for a joint statisticians/computer scientists event.

1. Which phrase sounds correct to you from CS/linguistics standpoint or how would you recommend to paraphrase it; the phrase describes a picture, so it'll go below the picture (no need to worry what's on the picture):

> > *This [i.e. the picture] is Python running my neural network in Tensorflow consuming all my CPU*

```
                      OR
```

> > *Training my neural network in Tensorflow is running in python consuming all my CPU*

2. Also, do the issues with CPU or GPU happen more often when running Tensorflow (assuming I have a single GPU)?
3. In terms of the correct terminology, is it more correct to say "python is running Tensorflow" or "Tensorflow is running in Python"?
4. If I add a "neural network" to that sentence, now is it "Python running my NN in Tensorflow" or "Tensorflow is running my NN in Python"?
5. Basically, and ideally, the sentence has to include the following phrases and convey the following ideas:

   - "Python consuming my CPU/GPU;" either "swallowing" or "consuming" must be in there
   - the fact that it is because of my [complicated NN model that probably sucks, i.e., a deprecating hint here]
   - the fact that it is because of my choice of Tensorflow (as opposed to PyTorch, etc)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For points as,

1. Training my neural network in Tensorflow is running in python consuming all my CPU
2. In my opinion issue happen more with CPU (if I consider it a normal CPU system) , and thats why they gave support for GPU (so Tenserflow execution could not load CPU more)
3. It would be best to say, Tenserflow library (or package) is running (or being used) in Python language.
4. Its like, Tenserflow is giving you some support for creating Neural Network (with ease) , so it can be portrayed as " Neural Network created using Tenserflow library is executing under Python language. "
5. Collectively it can be best written as , " Training my Neural Network using supportive NN from Tenserflow is executing in Python language that is consuming almost my system's complete CPU resources. "

Note: Please ignore my grammar mistakes. :P

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense! As far as language goes, would it make sense then to say:

1.  This is Python consuming all my CPU while I'm training my neural network in Tensorflow ?

Comment: please see for point 5 in my answer. Python is just being used to execute Tenserflow, but CPU utilization is due to the NN supported by TF.

Comment: oh great, I see your edits now, thank you a ton! I get it now!

Comment: pleasure all mine :)